# What is a jump rope good for?

Tags: exercise, vertical-jump, jump-rope

I have a jump rope, and my pulse sure goes up while jumping. But what am I exercising exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jump roping can be very effective in conditioning and strength.

Jump roping is a very helpful cardiovascular exercise. You're really exercising a complex system of muscles. You're not really isolating one muscle. You're exercising your upper body, core and lower muscles all in one action. You can't get more complete than that.

> **Upper Body**
>
> Because your arms are constantly
>   working to move the jump rope, the
>   upper body muscles are used
>   extensively, including your deltoids
>   (shoulders), back, forearms, biceps
>   and triceps. If you use a heavier
>   rope, your upper body will get more of
>   a workout because it is like adding
>   weight training to your jumping.
>
> **Core** 
>   Jumping rope requires balance, which draws on your core
>   muscles each time you jump and land
>   with the timing of the rope.
>   Abdominal, lower back and hip muscles
>   are all used as they help stabilize
>   and coordinate your movement.
>
> **Lower Body** Because you are constantly on your toes and making
>   vertical jumps, the calf muscles are
>   used a great deal in jumping rope. It
>   also uses the quadriceps (front of the
>   thighs), hamstrings (back of thighs)
>   and glutes (buttocks) for power and
>   strength. Adding in different moves
>   where you travel forward, backward or
>   side-to-side as you jump, will also
>   engage the smaller stabilizer muscles
>   in your lower body.

[Source](http://www.livestrong.com/article/25493-muscles-used-jump-rope/#ixzz1NrmHvweU)

Comment: That's awesome!! Great answer, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Jumping rope is also an excellent intro - or warmup - for plyometrics.

Comment: dont want to ask a new question for this, but:  how important is the rope, i mean will just jumping without the rope have the same benefits.  The ceiling clearance isn't high enough and i am a bit shy to do this in the open.

Comment: @kinjal that seems like a decent question, i'd say. I wouldn't be shy. Go head and post it. Seems like a different question.

Comment: We can jump and move arms without jump rope. I'm not trolling. You actually should modify your answer by indicating that jump rope is a useless equipment.

Answer (score 7):

If you are jumping on your toes tips then you are definetely working out your calves.

Also you can count that as a cardio if you can keep jumping for like 20 minutes. But if your heartbeat rate is going really high, no point to do that as a cardio exercise. You should be able to keep your heartbeat rate at a constant range, let's say 140-160 for most of the males.

Edit: Yep, i meant toes! :) Sorry, English is not my mother language.

Comment: On my finger tips? Strange images in my head... Anyways, I have just started so 20 mins without stopping would probably kill me :p Is it still good as cardio exercise if do it more like intervals? Jump until pulse gets a bit high, then wait for a bit until it settles, and so on?

Comment: I believe he meant your toes ;-)

Comment: HIIT is always good, especially for fat burning. So yep, you can do HIIT with it, very good exercise. You may end up with king kong calves in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the earlier answers that slow-paced jumproping can increase your cardio-respiratory endurance, but I think the primary benefit is increasing power and speed. This is why you see it used in any movie with a boxer getting ready for a fight.

Because of the rapid higher jumping required, double unders are the most effective way to use a jumprope.

Comment: Double unders? You mean having the rope pass under you twice between you touch the ground?

Comment: yes, like this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TfjmxeUsIs