# Are there any rope strength exercises?

Tags: exercise-equipment, home-exercise

Just by using a regular rope for rope jumping. Some of us are on a budget. :P
I can only think of one back exercise.

- Hang the rope over a bar (can be a pullup bar, or regular outdoors workout bar in a park).
- Grab the rope ends and let your body hang close to the ground with your legs in front of you, as if you were floating above ground with only your feet touching the ground. Keep your body tight and flat.
- Lift yourself up as much as you can if you were rowing.
- The lower the position, the harder the exercise.

Anyone has more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the term "suspension bands" on youtube you will get a variety of exercises that you may be able to adapt to your jump rope. The exercises target your trunk or core muscles, upper and lower body giving you a very good functional workout. TRX is a popular band and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gagl23KZs0U) shows a variety of exercises with the strap using your body weight as resistance.

A jump rope may not be strong enough to safely perform some of the exercises in the video. Since you are on a budget you can by straps and [make your own suspension band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ES5GN9k7BZw).

And of course you can get some pretty good [benefits from jumping rope](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2265/what-is-a-jump-rope-good-for/2279#2279).